# Target mobile only breakpoint

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind v3.

I have a custom background color being applied in an inline style with javascript:

```
<div style="background-color: RANDOM_GENERATED_COLOR" />
```

However in mobile breakpoint, I want it to ignore this background color, I want no background. So what I did was add `!bg-transparent`, using the "!" modifier I make it override the inline style:

```
<div style="background-color: RANDOM_GENERATED_COLOR" class="!bg-transparent" />
```

However I don't want the inline style overriden at all other breakpoints `sm` and above.

Is it possible to target `!bg-transparent` to mobile only breakpoint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may add custom [variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) which will apply styles on mobile screens only like `@media max-width: 640px`. Generally speaking with custom variants you can add any extra medias or state you need

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('mobile-only', "@media screen and (max-width: theme('screens.sm'))"); // instead of hard-coded 640px use sm breakpoint value from config. Or anything
    }),
  ],
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: RANDOM_GENERATED_COLOR" class="mobile-only:!bg-transparent" />
```

It is still required to use `!important` flag because of inline style

Colored [DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/3TkxtemAle?size=532x720) - resize demo screen at right

**Update:** Noitidart suggested another way of doing this with CSS variables - which is much cleaner and no need in `!important`

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        shading: 'var(--shading)'
      }
    }
  },
}
```

```html
<div style="--shading: RANDOM_GENERATED_COLOR;" class="bg-shading sm:bg-transparent">
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/d9nKoMEMUp?size=436x720)

Comment: Thanks! This works! I also was doing this other trick with css vars to avoid having to use important, what do you think of it? https://play.tailwindcss.com/RFYJx0XeHW?size=436x720

Comment: Oh, I like it! In a more tailwindish way you may even define CSS variable within config https://play.tailwindcss.com/d9nKoMEMUp?size=436x720

Comment: Oh wow that's super cool, this was an awesome learning experience!